# how to group by with annotate in django?

Tags: python, django

I tried absolutely everything with values().annotate() or aggregate() , or by following tutorials with Subquery I cant get what I want, let me explain :

There is what I get with `QuizzUserItem.objects.filter(examuser=user_exam).values('item__question', 'item')`

```
{'item': 759, 'item__question': 429}
{'item': 762, 'item__question': 430}
{'item': 763, 'item__question': 430}
{'item': 767, 'item__question': 431}
```

What I want is to group by item__question and get this result :

```
{'item': 759, 'item__question': 429}
{'item': 762,763 'item__question': 430}
{'item': 767, 'item__question': 431}
```

I start to think there is absolutely no way :/

---

What I tried :

`QuizzUserItem.objects.filter(examuser=user_exam).values('item__question','item').annotate(items_number=Count('item__question'))`

I got :

```
{'item': 759, 'item__question': 429, 'items_number': 1}
{'item': 762, 'item__question': 430, 'items_number': 1}
{'item': 763, 'item__question': 430, 'items_number': 1}
{'item': 767, 'item__question': 431, 'items_number': 1}
```

or

```
QuizzUserItem.objects.filter(examuser=user_exam).values('item__question').annotate(items_number=Count('item__question'))
```

This one is the closest result that I got :

```
{'item__question': 429, 'items_number': 1}
{'item__question': 430, 'items_number': 2}
{'item__question': 431, 'items_number': 1}
```

But I have not the item_ids 762,763...

Thank you for reading

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I use postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with the [**`ArrayAgg`** aggregate [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg) to obtain a list of items:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

QuizzUserItem.objects.filter(
    examuser=user_exam
).values(
    'item__question'
).annotate(
    items=ArrayAgg('item')
).order_by('item__question')
```